# Failed to correct my codes: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to retrieve data from SQL Server using PHP and SQLSRV, but im getting error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion
>   failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from
>   character string.

Can anyone help me with the issue here. Thanks

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

        require_once('connection.php');

        $recorded_on = $_POST['recorded_on'];
        $recorded_end = $_POST['recorded_on'];

        //$pin = $_POST['pin'];

        $sql = "
           SELECT * 
           FROM dbo.activity_logs 
           WHERE recorded_on between '.$recorded_on.' and '.$recorded_end.'
        ";
```

Comment: Dont inject, parametrise. Then this error can't happen.

Comment: What are the exact values of `$recorded_on` and `$recorded_end`? (what does `var_dump($recorded_on)` and/or `var_dump($recorded_end)` return)?

Comment: im using dates to retrieve data from database

Comment: If you use HTML `date` inpuit field in your HTML (`<input type="date" name="recorded_on"/>`) simply convert this input with `date('Ymd', strtotime($recorded_on));`. But, use parameters in your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it too

```
require_once('connection.php');

$recorded_on = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['recorded_on']));
$recorded_end = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['recorded_on']));

//$pin = $_POST['pin'];

$sql = "
   SELECT * 
   FROM dbo.activity_logs 
   WHERE DATE(recorded_on) between '".$recorded_on."' and '".$recorded_end."'
";
```